# Elasticsearch query multiple condition on same field

Tags: elasticsearch

These are the sample documents(event based) indexed in my ES cluster version 6.8

```
{
  "user_id": "user1",
  "account_id": "account1",
  "event_name": "event-1",
  "created_dt": "2019-09-30T08:40:42.297Z"
}

{
"user_id": "user1",
"account_id": "account1",
"event_name": "event-2",
"created_dt": "2019-10-30T08:40:42.297Z"
}

{
"user_id": "user2",
"account_id": "account1",
"event_name": "event-1",
"created_dt": "2019-10-30T08:40:42.297Z"
}
```

Mapping for the document

```
{
"mappings": {
"properties": {
  "user_id": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "account_id": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "event_name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "created_dt": {
    "type": "date"
  }
}
}
}
```

What i am trying to accomplish is fetching the list of users who have taken event_name "event-1" and "event-2" on stipulated time dynamically.

The query below which is having 2 must condition on same field "event_name" which eventually results empty.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "account_id": "account1"
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "event_name.raw": "event-1"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "created_dt": {
                "gte": "2019-09-30",
                "lte": "2019-10-30"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "event_name.raw": "event-2"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "created_dt": {
                "gte": "2019-10-30",
                "lte": "2019-11-05"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"user_list": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "user_id.raw"
  }
}
}
}
```

what is the ideal way to get the desired bucket documents? It can be done in SQL using IN and a sub query but couldn't look easier in ES

Comment: Please share your mappings

Comment: You should wrap your inner queries in another boolean query and use should instead of must. Read should as OR and must as AND. Using the must you will only match documents that contains both event-1 and event-2

Comment: @AssaelAzran mapping updated

Comment: @shivg What would you like to achieve? event_1 and event_2? does your query reflect the result you would like to get?

Comment: @EliasSoares, i get both the users "user1" and "users" as a result if i use should, the result only should returns "user1" as he has taken both the event on specified time

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is fetching the list of users who have taken event_name "event-1" and "event-2". no i don't get the results

Comment: Can you write a pseudo of what you want to achieve? not an elastic query

Comment: select user_id from event_table where event_name="event-1" and user_id in (select user_id from event_table where event_name="event-2")

Comment: you should have *event* as a _nested_ field inside *user*, so can have multiple event documents. Then you can query users which have an event which matches both conditions.

Comment: @BenG exactly, however the event data in our case is far bigger and can not be held in user data as it grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "account_id": "account1"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "event_name.raw": "event-1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "created_dt": {
                          "gte": "2019-09-30",
                          "lte": "2019-10-30"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "event_name.raw": "event-2"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "created_dt": {
                          "gte": "2019-10-30",
                          "lte": "2019-11-05"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "event_name.raw": "event-2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_list": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what if an user took only event-2 and not event-1, this query will fail on this condition